# Tests and SSIS packages on different solution do

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have some tests in one solution which run some SSIS packages from another solution. I use Visual Studio 2015. SSIS packages are made using SQL Server 2012. The problem is that when I run SSIS package from it's solution (on my machine) then everything  works fine but when I try to run the same package via tests from another solution I get the message:

> to run ssis package outside of sql server data tools you must install Derived Column of Integration Service or higher

The tests works fine in TeamCity on server. I cannot run them because of that message only locally.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I think you are missing SSDT on you local machine. Visual Studio 2015 is there but you need to have the Integration services to execute package from local.

Comment: You [need to install the SQL Server Integration Serivces Service](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/49786/2131) on that machine

Comment: I have had it already. Like I said I can run SSIS package on my machine but I can not using tests which execute SSIS packages from other solution. But I do everything on my local machine

Comment: @billinkc  you were right - I did not have SQL Server Integration Service and this is what I needed :) Thanks